# install build python from source libraries virtual app

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I work at a large company and do not have admin rights. The company provides Python 3.3 which is run as a virtual app-v package from a server.

I would like to install Matplotlib, Scipy and Numpy. Since I cannot use the installers on my local machine, and presumably cannot run installers on the Q drive running the Python app-v package, how do I build Matplotlib or Scipy from source or install Python libraries in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use Anaconda: https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/ . Comes with those packages built and you wouldn't need admin rights

Comment: Under Windows, you could run [WinPython](https://code.google.com/p/winpython/) out of a flash drive, and it comes with all those and many more preinstalled.